# Equivalent Stopping Times for Brownian Motions

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-analysis

For standard Brownian motion $B$, define stopping time $T_1:=\inf\{t>0: B_t = 3\}$ and $T_2:=\inf\{t>0: B_t = -3\}$ and $T_3 := \min\{T_1, T_2\}$.

1. Can I say that $T_3 = \inf\{t>0, B_t \in \{-3, 3\}\}$?
2. In addition, how to relate $T_1$ and $T_2$ in terms of their distributions? I would imagine some easy relationship between their moment generating function or Laplace transform since $-B$ is also a Brownian motion. Hence, $T_2$ is the counterpart of $T_1$ for $-B$. Is there any available result for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, this one is very simple and has nothing to do with probability:
   $$
   \min(\inf\{t: B_t = a\}, \inf\{t: B_t = -a\})
   = \inf\{t: B_t = a \text{ or } B_t = -a\}$$
2. Indeed, as in probability law for stochastic processes $(B_t) = (-B_t)$, 
   $T_1$ and $T_2$ have the same distribution:

$$
Ef(\inf\{t: B_t = a\}) =^* \inf\{t: -B_t = a\}
= \inf\{t: B_t = -a\}
$$

where you use the fact that  $(B_t) = (-B_t)$ in the $*$ed equality.

Comment: maybe in another question? ;) this is quite long to be explained just in a comment. But just a hint: it is based on rescaling properties of the Brownian motion.

Comment: you are welcome. did you see my edit?

Comment: the lsat comment.

Comment: exactly.${{{}}}$

Comment: no, I don't think so.

Comment: just open another question!